# Difficult case with TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, function, plotly, scalar

I am trying to use **plotly** to graph a huge function which is in turn a sum of other functions - I want to append the smaller functions to arrays and add them up to the final function. Process with simple functions works, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np 
import plotly.graph_objects as go
pi = math.pi
X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]
x=[pi*2,4]
values1 = pi*X*X+Y*Y
values2 = Z*Z
values.append(values1*x[0])
values.append(values2*x[1])
valuestot=values[0]+values[1]
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Isosurface(
    x=X.flatten(),
    y=Y.flatten(),
    z=Z.flatten(),
    value=valuestot.flatten(),
    isomin=-0.1,
    isomax=0.1
    ))
fig.show()
```

However, problem occurs when I use a longer function (respective to values1), for example:

```
n1s2 = nns21 * (((3 * nas21 / pi) ** (1 / 4)) * math.exp( -nas21 * ((X + cXN1) ** 3 + (Y + cYN1) ** 2 + (Z + cZN1) ** 2))) + nns22 * ( ((2 * nas22 / pi) ** (1 / 4)) * math.exp( -nas22 * ((X + cXN1) ** 2 + (Y + cYN1) ** 3 + (Z + cZN1) ** 2)))
```

gives the **TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars** error for the line of the function in the code.
I tried all the solutions with np.vectorize() given on different forums, yet that does not help, as python presumably reads the long line as a list of items. How could I make the line read as a single function which is recognized by python? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Succeeded - got a suggestion from a brilliant CS student to change math.exp() to np.exp() so that different exponents account for separate mgrid vectors (X,Y,Z).